# Time derivative of L2-norm for heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, normed-spaces

Are you able to say that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}(||\nabla u ||_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}) \geq 0 
\end{align}
$$
for the linear heat equation
$$
\begin{align}
u_{t}(x)-\Delta u(x) &=0, & & x \in \Omega, &  t>0 \\
u(x, t) &=0, & & x \in \partial \Omega, & t>0 \\
u(x, 0) &=u_{0}(x), & & x \in \Omega
\end{align}
$$

Comment: What norm are we talking about?

Comment: It is the L2-norm.

Comment: I will answer in an hour or two...

Comment: I tried it but I don't think that it holds honestly...

Comment: Derivative should be negative...